# Running parallel instances of a single job/rule on Snakemake

Tags: snakemake

Unexperienced, self-tought "coder" here, so please be understanding :]

I am trying to learn and use Snakemake to construct pipeline for my analysis. Unfortunatly, I am unable to run multiple instances of a single job/rule at the same time. My workstation is not a computing cluster, so I cannot use this option. I looked for an answer for hours, but either there is non, or I am not knowledgable enough to understand it. 
So: is there a way to run multiple instances of a single job/rule simultaneously?

If You would like a concrete example:

Lets say I want to analyze a set of 4 .fastq files using fastqc tool. So I input a command:

```
time snakemake -j 32
```

and thus run my code, which is:

```
SAMPLES, = glob_wildcards("{x}.fastq.gz")

rule Raw_Fastqc:
    input:
            expand("{x}.fastq.gz", x=SAMPLES)
    output:
            expand("./{x}_fastqc.zip", x=SAMPLES),
            expand("./{x}_fastqc.html", x=SAMPLES)
    shell:
            "fastqc {input}"
```

I would expect snakemake to run as many instances of fastqc as possible on 32 threads (so easily all of my 4 input files at once). In reality. this command takes about 12 minutes to finish. Meanwhile, utilizing GNU parallel from inside snakemake

```
shell:
    "parallel fastqc ::: {input}"
```

I get results in 3 minutes. Clearly there is some untapped potential here.

Thanks!

Comment: Similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50828233/1878788. This seems a common pitfall.

Comment: Yes, I saw this topic, but incorrectly I thought that my problem is different because I do not use computing clusters. Hence replicate question. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

If I am not wrong, `fastqc` works on each fastq file separately, and therefore your implementation doesn't take advantage of parallelization feature of snakemake. This can be done by [defining the targets](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#targets) as shown below using `rule all`.

```
from pathlib import Path

SAMPLES = [Path(f).name.replace('.fastq.gz', '')  for f in glob_wildcards("{x}.fastq.gz") ]

rule all:
    input:
        expand("./{sample_name}_fastqc.{ext}", 
                        sample_name=SAMPLES, ext=['zip', 'html'])

rule Raw_Fastqc:
    input:
            "{x}.fastq.gz", x=SAMPLES
    output:
            "./{x}_fastqc.zip", x=SAMPLES,
            "./{x}_fastqc.html", x=SAMPLES
    shell:
            "fastqc {input}"
```

Comment: Thank You! You are absolutely correct! Although I did not use the exact code You provided, the parallel processing did work when I included "all" rule and removed "expand"s from subsequent rule. The only problem now is that I do not understand why is the snakemake acting like this. Perhaps You could point me to appropriate tutorial/manual (if it is explained at http://snakemake.readthedocs.io, I cannot see it or understand it...)?

Comment: @AdrianS85 Snakemake will parallelize by running several instances of a rule (i.e. "jobs") in parallel (with different values of the wildcards, as determined from its output). When you use `expand`, you "consume/resolve" wildcards. A rule whose output is an `expand` over an `x` wildcard says: "One job will output multiple files", not "One job will output the file corresponding to a given value of `x`". The typical way to do is to have an `all` "driving rule", that has an `expand` in its input, just to say "In the end, I want all those files", and a "driven rule", with a wildcard in its output.

Comment: @AdrianS85 I tried to develop these explanations here: https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/pull-requests/307/helping-understand-expand-and/diff Hopefully this will end up integrated in the official documentation and improved.

Answer (score 1):

To add to JeeYem's answer above, you can also define the number of resources to reserve for each job using the ['threads' property](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#threads) of each rule, as so:

```
rule Raw_Fastqc:
input:
        "{x}.fastq.gz", x=SAMPLES
output:
        "./{x}_fastqc.zip", x=SAMPLES,
        "./{x}_fastqc.html", x=SAMPLES
threads: 4
shell:
        "fastqc --threads {threads} {input}"
```

Because fastqc itself can use multiple threads per task, you might even get additional speedups over the `parallel` implementation.

Snakemake will then automatically allocate as many jobs as can fit within the total threads provided by the top-level call:

`snakemake -j 32`, for example, would execute up to 8 instances of the `Raw_Fastqc` rule.

Comment: Thanks for a hint! Unfortunatly, I dont think it works for `fastqc` After snakemake parallelization worked, I tried adding `--threads 4` to `shell: "fastqc"`, but it did not speed up the execution.