# use snakemake pair-end bwa alignment

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake, snakeyaml

I am new in using snakemake, I have a simple problem when doing mapping in snakemake. I have couples of _1.fastq.gz & _2.fastq.gz and I would like to do pair-end mapping for around 10 pairs of fastq.gz. So I wrote a snakemake file for this.

```
import os
import snakemake.io
import glob

(SAMPLES,READS,) = glob_wildcards("raw/{sample}_{read}.fastq.gz")
READS=["1","2"]
REF="/data/data/reference/refs/ucsc.hg19.fasta.gz"

rule all:
    input: expand("raw/{sample}.bam",sample=SAMPLES)

rule bwa_map:
    input:
        ref=REF,
        r1=expand("raw/{sample}_{read}.fastq.gz",sample=SAMPLES,read=READS),
        r2=expand("raw/{sample}_{read}.fastq.gz",sample=SAMPLES,read=READS)

    output: "raw/{sample}.bam"

    shell: "bwa mem -M -t 8 {input.ref} {input.r1} {input.r2} | samtools view -Sbh - > {output}"
```

Error:

```
RuleException:
CalledProcessError in line 17 of /data/data/Samples/snakemake-example/WGS-test/step2.smk:
Command ' set -euo pipefail;  bwa mem -M -t 8 /data/data/reference/refs/ucsc.hg19.fasta.gz raw/sub1_1.fastq.gz raw/sub1_2.fastq.gz raw/sub2_1.fastq.gz raw/sub2_2.fastq.gz raw/sub1_1.fastq.gz raw/sub1_2.fastq.gz raw/sub2_1.fastq.gz raw/sub2_2.fastq.gz raw/sub1_1.fastq.gz raw/sub1_2.fastq.gz raw/sub2_1.fastq.gz raw/sub2_2.fastq.gz raw/sub1_1.fastq.gz raw/sub1_2.fastq.gz raw/sub2_1.fastq.gz raw/sub2_2.fastq.gz | samtools view -Sbh - > raw/sub2.bam ' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  File "/data/data/Samples/snakemake-example/WGS-test/step2.smk", line 17, in __rule_bwa_map
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/bioinfo/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 56, in run
```

My desired output would be like generate all 10 bam files like

sub1.bam
sub2.bam
sub3.bam
...

It looks like put all the fastq files into a command. how can i separate them and run pair by pair automatically without using hard code method. Please advice.

Comment: This is a common issue for snakemake beginners (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/50828233/1878788): `expand` is generally needed only in the input of a rule that needs to gather results from several instances of an "upstream" rule. The `all` rule is typically used to do this gathering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first rule (here `rule all`) specifies the files that you would like to create during your snakemake workflow.

For a given file, `f`, in `rule all::input`, snakemake will look through all the rules and try to find one that can create `f` (based on pattern matching on the `output` segment of each rule).

Suppose `f = raw/my_sample.bam`

Once `snakemake` has found a rule that can create `f`, it will determine all the input files required to make that file.

So here, snakemake finds that `f = raw/my_sample.bam` can be created by `rule bwa_map` (since `f` matches the pattern `raw/<anything>.bam`) and then determines what files are required to make `f` based on the `input` segment.

Snakemake thinks: I can make `raw/my_sample.bam` if I have
the file `ref="/data/data/reference/refs/ucsc.hg19.fasta.gz"`
the files `r1=expand("raw/{sample}_{read}.fastq.gz",sample=SAMPLES,read=READS)`
and the files `r2=expand("raw/{sample}_{read}.fastq.gz",sample=SAMPLES,read=READS)`

In the `expand`, `r1` expands `sample` to each value in SAMPLES and `read` to each value in READS. But you have 10 values in SAMPLES and 2 values in READS, so `r1` expands to 20 different file paths for each output file that it is attempting to make. It is ignoring the `sample` wildcard that is present in the `output` clause (because you've overwritten it in the `expand` call).

**You have to let the wildcards that are defined in the output clause bubble up to the input clause**:

```
import os
import snakemake.io
import glob

(SAMPLES,READS,) = glob_wildcards("raw/{sample}_{read}.fastq.gz")
READS=["1","2"]
REF="/data/data/reference/refs/ucsc.hg19.fasta.gz"

rule all:
    input: expand("raw/{sample}.bam",sample=SAMPLES)

rule bwa_map:
    input:
        ref=REF,
        # determine `r1` based on the {sample} wildcard defined in `output`
        # and the fixed value `1` to indicate the read direction
        r1="raw/{sample}_1.fastq.gz",
        # determine `r2` based on the {sample} wildcard similarly
        r2="raw/{sample}_2.fastq.gz"

    output: "raw/{sample}.bam"

    # better to pass in the threads than to hardcode them in the shell command
    threads: 8

    shell: "bwa mem -M -t {threads} {input.ref} {input.r1} {input.r2} | samtools view -Sbh - > {output}"
```

I'd urge you to have a look at how the rule for `bwa` alignment is written in the snakemake wrappers resource (you might consider using the wrapper as well): https://snakemake-wrappers.readthedocs.io/en/stable/wrappers/bwa/mem.html

Off-topic: From a code review perspective, I question why you are outputting aligned data to your `raw` directory? Would it make more sense to output your aligned data to `align` or `aligned` instead? You also appear to be importing from packages that you don't use.